# Changing the UI of the longlistSelector

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to change the UI of the LongListSelector in windows phone applications?

If so how can I do that if not why it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You change the UI by providing custom UI definition/style for `ItemTemplate`, `GroupHeaderTemplate`, `JumpListStyle`, `ListHeaderTemplate`, `ListFooterTemplate`, and some other properties of LongListSelector.

Find details on how to that in [this post](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth) from geekchamp.com and see [3 sample projects](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/05/23/windows-phone-8-xaml-longlistselector.aspx) that demonstrates possible usage of LongListSelector from blogs.windows.com